# How to use even-odd filling rule either as a clipper or with gradient?

Tags: pstricks, path-clipping

I just noticed that even-odd filling rule can only be used for solid and hatched filling. Sometimes, I need even-odd rule for gradient and as a clipper. How to do so? My code speaks the details.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-grad}

\newpsstyle{gradient}
{
    fillstyle=gradient,
    gradbegin=red,
    gradend=yellow,
    gradangle=30,
    gradmidpoint=0.5,
}

\newpsstyle{fill}
{
    fillstyle=eofill,
    fillcolor=orange,
}

\def\YinYang#1{%
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pscustom[style=#1,dimen=monkey]
    {
        \pscircle(0,0){2}
        \moveto(.25,1)
        \pscircle(0,1){.25}
        \moveto(0,0)
        \psarc(0,-1){1}{90}{270}
        \psarc(0,0){2}{270}{90}
        \psarcn(0,1){1}{90}{270}
        \closepath
        \moveto(.25,-1)
        \pscircle(0,-1){.25}
    }
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\YinYang{fill}

% there are 2 failed cases:
% 1. with gradient style \YinYang{gradient}
% 2. using the \pscustom of \YingYang as a clipper

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Note

Please don't suggest me to modify the paths and use zero filling rule.

### Edit

Based on Herbert's answer below, the following case in which the path is used as a clipper still does not work.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=2]{example-grid-100x100pt}}

\psset
{
    xunit=.25\wd\IBox,
    yunit=.25\ht\IBox,
}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
\psclip{%
    \pscustom[dimen=monkey]
    {
        \code{/clip /eoclip load def}
        \pscircle(0,0){2}
        \moveto(.25,1)
        \pscircle(0,1){.25}
        \moveto(0,0)
        \psarc(0,-1){1}{90}{270}
        \psarc(0,0){2}{270}{90}
        \psarcn(0,1){1}{90}{270}
        \closepath
        \moveto(.25,-1)
        \pscircle(0,-1){.25}
    }}
\rput(0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\endpsclip
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the key-value formats defined for filling does not follow a logical pattern.

Comment: Not an answer (but I played around with it): `\def\psfs@gradienteofill{\psfs@gradient\psfs@eofill}` allows `fillstyle=gradientoefill`. This actually does the gradient first and then fills the correct path with white (or whatever the `fillcolor` is).

Comment: The culprit in your last MWE (with Edit heading) is the unit settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\def\YinYang#1{%
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pscustom[style=#1,dimen=middle]{   
        \code{ /clip /eoclip load def } %%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \pscircle(0,0){2}
        \moveto(.25,1)
        \pscircle(0,1){.25}
        \moveto(0,0)
        \psarc(0,-1){1}{90}{270}
        \psarc(0,0){2}{270}{90}
        \psarcn(0,1){1}{90}{270}
        \closepath
        \moveto(.25,-1)
        \pscircle(0,-1){.25}
    }
\end{pspicture}}
```

[image]

and the same with a picture:

```
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
\psclip{%
    \pscustom[dimen=middle]
    {
        \code{ /clip /eoclip load def }
        \pscircle(0,0){2}
        \moveto(.25,1)
        \pscircle(0,1){.25}
        \moveto(0,0)
        \psarc(0,-1){1}{90}{270}
        \psarc(0,0){2}{270}{90}
        \psarcn(0,1){1}{90}{270}
        \closepath
        \moveto(.25,-1)
        \pscircle(0,-1){.25}
    }}
\rput(0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\endpsclip
\end{pspicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the `\closepath` necessary in this case? I noticed there is no difference when  I removed the `\closepath`.

Comment: The first and third `\moveto` are no longer needed in the current pstricks.

Comment: but doesn't hurt ...